# Mathematical formulation of an optimization problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, optimization, set-partition, dynamic-programming, mixed-integer-programming

I have the following optimization problem at hand.

There are `N` integer numbers, $a_{i},a_{i+1},\dots,a_{n}$ where $a_{i} > 0$.

We need to partition these numbers into `d` sets and partitions should be contiguous. Please assume valid combination of $N$ and $d$. For example, a valid partition would be like (assume $N = 10$ and  $d = 3$):

$a_{1}, a_{2}, a_{3} \quad |\quad a_{4}, a_{5}, a_{6} \quad |\quad a_{7}, a_{8}, a_{9},a_{10}$

Now, in each partition, there will be a maximum value, call it as $a^{k}$ for the $k$th partition where $1 \le k \le d$. We need to minimize the $\sum_{k = 1}^{d} a^{k}$.

So, my approach was to break down this optimization problem into subproblems:

for example, If $f(i,k)$ = Optimal sum when we partition $1$ to $i$ numbers into $k$ partitions.

Then, $f(i,k+1) = \text{min}\left[f(j,k) + \text{max}\left(a_{j+1},a_{j+2},\dots,a_{i} \right) \right] \quad \text{where} \quad j < i$.

With this formulation, we can calculate smaller subproblems first and then construct the bigger subproblems.

But, I don't consider discussing the above approach here, because of its algorithmic nature. I want to know if there is another way of handling this optimization problem in a more mathematical way instead of algorithmic treatment.

Sorry for the term "mathematical way", because I am not aware of such techniques if exist.

Thanks!

Comment: you can phrase it as a mixed integer optimization problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve the problem via integer linear programming as follows.  For each pair $(i,j)$ with $1 \le i \le j \le n$, let binary decision variable $x_{i,j}$ indicate whether part $\{a_i,\dots,a_j\}$ appears in the partition.  The problem is to minimize $$\sum_{i,j} \max(a_i,\dots,a_j) x_{i,j}$$ subject to
\begin{align}
\sum_{i,j} x_{i,j} &= d \tag1 \\
\sum_{i,j: i \le k \le j} x_{i,j} &= 1 &&\text{for $k\in \{1,\dots,n\}$} \tag2\\
\end{align}
Constraint $(1)$ selects exactly $d$ parts.
Constraint $(2)$ forces each element to appear in exactly one part.

Comment: nice choice for the decision variable

Comment: Thanks, @LinAlg. It naturally captures both the contiguity requirement and the nonlinearity of $\max$.